# what is the regexp for Ipv4 address without using ipv4address and socket or any other builtin modules?

Tags: python-3.x

Am trying a simplest way to find the regexp for valid ip address without 
    using builtin like socket or ipv4address or any other builtin . i have 
    tried couple of regexp but its not matching the valid host ip's

```
>>> x = 'hello 10.10.10.10  20.20.20.20 baby 2000.20000.200000.2000'
>>> y = re.findall(r'[0-255]+\.[0-255]+\.[0-255]+\.[0-255]+',x)
>>> y
['10.10.10.10', '20.20.20.20', '2000.20000.200000.2000']
```

Comment: x = 'hello 10.10.10.10  20.20.20.20 baby 2000.20000.200000.2000'
>>> ipnew=re.findall(r'^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$',x)
>>> ipnew
[]
>>>

Comment: i tried the above method too but does't work for fetching valid ip's

Answer (score 1):

You have a correct IPV4 address regex, and if you want to find multiple matches you do findall(), but notice my regex does not have the starting (^) nor the ending ($) symbols. These symbols mean that your text will ONLY match if it starts and ends with the given regex.

```
import re
IPV4_REGEX = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|(?:1[0-9]|[1-9])?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|(?:1[0-9]|[1-9])?[0-9])"
x = 'hello 10.10.10.10  20.20.20.20 baby 2000.20000.200000.2000'
result = re.findall(IPV4_REGEX, x)
print(result)
```